# Multiple Record Displaying

Tags: duplicates, distinct, record, multiple-columns, distinct-values

I am trying to display Distinct record on the basis of specific field, but Query returns the whole record with repetition values.
Here is my query.

`SELECT  DISTINCT [type], ITEM_ID  FROM Item ORDER BY [type]`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [type], ITEM_ID FROM Item ORDER BY ID
```

it seems you can not use same field for both distinct and order by clause